# mongodb upsert multiple documents using one json

Tags: json, mongodb

I receive JSON data which contains multiple documents and I am able to insert that data into a mongodb collection using `collection.insert`

Once I have populated my collection I can receive a subset of the JSON data which contains updates (edits and new documents) to the original data. I know that I can split up my JSON into the separate documents to loop through and use

```
collection.update{ id: <document id> },
{
 <document to update>;
},
{ upsert: true }
```

for each document to upsert it to my collection, but is there a way to upsert JSON containing multiple documents based on matching IDs, as I am able to do with `collection.insert`?

Comment: you mean this? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the docs, but I thought that this would allow the update to happen all at once, but would still require me to loop through the documents within the original JSON.

Comment: You are right that a bulk upsert improves things just by turning multiple server roundtrips into fewer bundles of operations. You have to loop through the JSON and set the conditions for the upsert, which in your case is the simplest thing of an upsert by `_id`. AFAIK, there's no helper method to handle this case for you.

Comment: Thanks, I've done it that way now, just didn't want to go the long way round if there was a neater way of doing it.